# how decrypt with decipher.doFinal(file_encrypt)

Tags: android, encryption

I doing encryption and decryption of document. Initially i read the file in byte array and passed that byte array to my encrypeted method. Upto 50MB size , i am able to encrypt the file without any issue. But if i increase my file SIZE to 80 MB , it is faling in cipher.doFinal() saying out of memoryException.
So how to encrypt bigger file without any issues? and also is doFinal() method have any size limitation. Please let me know.
and this is my code:

public String decrypt(byte[] file_encrypt) throws Exception {

```
    String key22 = myKey;
    byte[] b = key22.getBytes();

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(b, "DESede");
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);    
    final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(file_encrypt);


    try {
        String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + ".android";
        String dir2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + ".android/.androidmain";
        File folder = new File(dir); //folder name
        File folder2 = new File(dir2); //folder name
        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();
        if (!folder2.exists())
            folder2.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + ".android/.androidmain/file");


        if (file.exists()) {
          //  Toast.makeText(contInst, "111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
          //  Toast.makeText(contInst, "3333", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));


        bos.write(plainText);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();          
       videoplay.setSource(Uri.fromFile(file));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When encrypting or decrypting, both the plain text and the encrypted text should be in the memory(RAM) at least one time.

But Java allow you to use limited memory. If you want to go from 50MB to 80MB, maybe using `android:largeHeap=true` in the application of your manifest will work. But if you want even a higher limit, you may want to perform the encryption by splitting up the file and performing encryption piece by piece.

Comment: yes i know must chunk chunk the byte array and try it but didn't work